# ImportError: No module named toolbox.pairinggroup

Tags: python, charm-crypto

I have installed charm cryptography library but when I try to run a file using this library I am getting error like:

```
File "maabe_rw12.py", line 17, in <module>
    from toolbox.pairinggroup import * ImportError: No module named toolbox.pairinggroup
```

Comment: posting the entire traceback and the file you are trying to run would help

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
from charm.toolbox.pairinggroup import *
```

Found here: http://jhuisi.github.io/charm/cryptographers.html#group-abstractions

How did you install `charm`? Where on your filesystem is the library? You can see that it is not on your path if you:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)  # `print sys.path` if on python 2.X
```

Perhaps you can append the directory that charm is in using `sys.path.append`; although, this is usually not the optimal solution.

Comment: ya i tried as you said but still i am getting this error ImportError: No module named charm.toolbox.pairinggroup.i even tried adding paring group like this ...from charm.toolbox.pairinggroup import PairingGroup,ZR,G1,G2,GT,pair

Comment: how did you install charm?

Comment: ya i did...but still the same error...i even followed platform manual for installing charm.,...is there any way to rectify this error....

Comment: i installed all the dependencies gmp,pbc,openssl,m4,etc....like specified in that platform manual...

Comment: ya i tried reinstalling charm library but now i got a new error while using the make command /Charm-Crypto-0.42$ sudo make install/usr/bin/python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 2, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup
ImportError: No module named setuptools
make: *** [install] Error 1
kindly rectify

Comment: from charm.toolbox.pairinggroup import *
from cryptobase import *
from charm.toolbox.secretutil import SecretUtil
from charm.toolbox.ABEnc import *
from charm.BenchmarkFunctions import *

Answer (score 0):

All what you need to do is import pairinggroup to your code :

```
from charm.toolbox.pairinggroup import PairingGroup,ZR,G1,G2,GT,pair
```